# PHP curl multi handle doesn't work for some websites, but they do work not multi handled

Tags: php, facebook, curl, asynchronous

I have this piece of simple code. It works except for facebook in multi handle. I don't get respond from it even though I get respond from facebook not multi handled. What could be possibly wrong? I use XAMPP and curl error didn't appear. Another thing I have to mention is that it is the only working for me way of executing multi handle. The other ones did infinite loops or gave no respond.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://m.facebook.com';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$page=curl_exec($ch);

echo $page;

$ch1 = curl_init();
$ch2 = curl_init();
$ch3 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "https://jbzdy.pl/");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://m.facebook.com/");
curl_setopt($ch3, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.reddit.com");

$mh = curl_multi_init();

curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch1);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch2);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch3);

$running = null;
do
{
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
}
while($running > 0);

$page1 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch1);
$page2 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch2);
$page3 = curl_multi_getcontent($ch3);

echo $page1;
echo $page2;
echo $page3; 

echo curl_error($ch2);
?>
```

Comment: well one or more of those sites is known to detect and block automated scrapping

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in 301 redirect, try to add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Well, it works but not exactly. Now facebook tells me to update my browser.

Comment: @TomekOciepka So try to set useragent: curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0');

Comment: _“Now facebook tells me to update my browser”_ - because, as already said, Facebook does not want you to do this in the first place. It is against their ToS, and of course they have measures in place to detect what you are doing. Sure you can try to add bits and bobs to the request to make it look more like it was made by a “real” browser ... but rest assured, they’ll be stepping up their game, too ...